# Is there a formal method for 'walking' XML in Python?

Tags: python, xml, os.walk

I have been learning how to extract parts of XML using the dom.minidom function, and I can return specific elements and attributes successfully.

I have a number of large XML files I want to parse, and push all the results into a db. 
Is there are a function like os.walk that I can use to and extract elements from the XML in a logical way that preserves the hierarchical structure?

The XML is pretty basic and is very straight forward:

```
<InternalSignature ID="9" Specificity="Generic">
 <ByteSequence Reference="BOFoffset">
  <SubSequence Position="1" SubSeqMinOffset="0" SubSeqMaxOffset="0" MinFragLength="0">
  <Sequence>49492A00</Sequence> 
  <DefaultShift>5</DefaultShift> 
  <Shift Byte="00">1</Shift> 
  <Shift Byte="2A">2</Shift> 
  <Shift Byte="49">3</Shift> 
  </SubSequence>
 </ByteSequence>
</InternalSignature>
<InternalSignature ID="10" Specificity="Generic">
 <ByteSequence Reference="BOFoffset">
  <SubSequence Position="1" SubSeqMinOffset="0" SubSeqMaxOffset="0" MinFragLength="0">
  <Sequence>4D4D002A</Sequence> 
  <DefaultShift>5</DefaultShift> 
  <Shift Byte="2A">1</Shift> 
  <Shift Byte="00">2</Shift> 
  <Shift Byte="4D">3</Shift> 
  </SubSequence>
 </ByteSequence>
</InternalSignature>
```

Is there a formal method of crawling the XML and (in this small example) extracting the elements that relate to each specific InternalSignature?
I can see how to call things via a list using the minidom.parse and the .GetElementsByName methods, but I'm not sure how you associate elements into their hierarchical representation.

So far I have found a tutorial that shows how to return various values:

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse("file.xml")
Versionlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('FFSignatureFile')
VersionRef = Versionlist[0]
Version = VersionRef.attributes["Version"]
DateCreated = VersionRef.attributes["DateCreated"]
print Version.value
print DateCreated.value
InternalSignatureList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('InternalSignature')
InternalSignatureRef = InternalSignatureList[0]
SigID = InternalSignatureRef.attributes["ID"]
SigSpecificity = InternalSignatureRef.attributes["Specificity"]
print SigID.value 
print SigSpecificity.value
print len(InternalSignatureList)
```

I can see from the last line (len) that there is 134 elements in the InternalSignatureList, and essentially I want to be able to extract all the elements inside each InternalSignature as an individual record and flick it into a db.

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure if I understand the question but how about [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) (possible combined with `getchildren()` - at least `lxml` supports using it to traverse an XML tree.

Answer (score 3):

( What have you tried? )

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

e = ElementTree.fromstring(xmlstring)
e.findall("ByteSequence")
```